# Mostrar lista de enteros

Tags: c, lista

El programa compila pero solo muestra el último elemento de la lista en ser ingresados y no el resto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct nodo{
    int valor;  
    struct nodo *sig;
};

int main(){
    int opcion;
    int valor;
    struct nodo *lista;
    lista = NULL;
    struct nodo *aux;
    aux = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));

    do{
        printf("\n1- insertar elemento\n");
        printf("2- mostrar lista \n");
        printf("0- salir\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);
        switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            printf("ingrese un valor: ");
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            if(lista==NULL){
                lista = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
                lista->valor=valor;
                lista->sig=NULL;
            }
            else{
                lista->sig=aux;
                aux->valor=valor;
                aux->sig=NULL;
                aux=lista;
            }
            break;
        case 2: while(aux!=NULL){ //<- solo muestra el primer valor
            printf("el valor del elemento es %d \n", aux->valor); 
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        break;
        case 0: printf("fin del programa \n");
        break;
        }
    }while (opcion !=0);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He realizado una serie de modificaciones en tu código para que guarde todo los elementos que quieras en la lista y luego los visualice. Tenias mal la forma de reservar y de guardar los datos en la lista y la forma en que lo visualizabas. Espero haberte ayudado y cualquier cosa pregunta :)

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct nodo
{
    int valor;  
    struct nodo *sig;
};

int main()
{
    int opcion;
    int valor;
    struct nodo *principioLista = NULL;
    struct nodo *finalLista = NULL;
    struct nodo *aux;    

    do{
        printf("\n1- insertar elemento\n");
        printf("2- mostrar lista \n");
        printf("0- salir\n");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);

        switch(opcion)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("ingrese un valor: ");
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            aux = (struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
            aux->valor = valor;
            if(principioLista == NULL)
            {
                principioLista = aux;
                aux->sig = NULL;
                finalLista = aux;
            }
            else
            {
                finalLista->sig = aux;
                aux->sig = NULL;
                finalLista = aux;
            }
            break;
        case 2: 
            while(principioLista != NULL)
            { 
                printf("el valor del elemento es %d \n", principioLista->valor); 
                principioLista = principioLista->sig;
            }
            break;
            case 0: printf("fin del programa \n");
            break;
        }
    }while(opcion !=0);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tira error en la línea que dice `aux = (nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));`

La variable nodo no está definida

Comment: A mi no me da error de ningún tipo amigo. Y el nodo si esta declarado antes del do while --> `struct nodo *aux;`

Comment: ya se donde esta el error Alejandro, en la reserva de nodo debe ir struct, quedaria asi: `aux = (struct nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));`

Answer (score 0):

Se te ha olvidado una cosa: Reservar memoria para cada nuevo número. La sentencia

```
aux = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
```

La tienes que volver a hacer cada vez que crees un nuevo nodo, o estarás reusando el mismo contínuamente, con lo que siempre acabarás con un único elemento.

El cuerpo del else tendría que añadir esa línea y eliminar la última para que lista apunte al primer elemento por muchos que añadas

Comment: ¿Y como hago eso?

Comment: Añádela como primera línea en el else

Comment: hago esto y sigue andando mal
   `if(lista==NULL){
    lista = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista->valor=valor;
    lista->sig=NULL;
   }
   else
   {
    aux = (struct nodo *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    lista->sig=aux;
    aux->valor=valor;
    aux->sig=NULL;
    aux=lista;
   }`

Comment: solo funciona bien si agregas solo 2 elementos

Comment: Hay más cosas que arreglar, mira mi edición